# Rounding to a Significant Digit, VB

Tags: vb.net, rounding

In the vb function 'round', I want to be able to round to one digit after the decimal. It seems like in the following code:

> round([SHAPE_Area]/10000, 1) & " ha"

Where I want to round to to one place after the decimal, if the value for that palce after the decimal is 0, then it rounds to a whole number (i.e. 1 instead of 1.0) I would like it to round to 1.0. The [SHAPE_Area] field is of type 'Double'. I'm not sure if that has any significance to the vb rounding function and how it rounds.

Comment: one thing has nothing to do with the other. Round does rounding. ToString() does converting to a formatted string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use .ToString() with the correct [Format String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) instead:

```
([SHAPE_Area]/10000).ToString("F1") & " ha"
```

Answer (score 1):

The number is rounded correctly. The number `1` is the same thing as the number `1.0`.

What you want to do is formatting the number:

```
Dim formatted As String = String.Format("{0:N1} ha", SHAPE_Area)
```